# iPad safari new top-bar messed up

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, safari, ipad

The new top-bar as seen from an iPad. This is the SO home page.

> [image: Messed up topbar]

iPad Mini 1

iOS 8

Comment: Did you try turning it on and off again?

Comment: @Developer yes, just force quit and turned off iPad, and the problem is the same

Comment: On my old Safari desktop version 5.x on Windows I have the same effect. All the fancy css isn't supported

Comment: I guess it might be because iPad is oldish and on iOS 8. I hope they provide a 'simple' option for older devices/OSs

Comment: I believe that @Developer was referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8...

Comment: Same layout problem happens with Konqueror on regular KDE desktop from opensuse 42.2. Makes SO completely unusable.

Comment: And now it suddenly works for me.

Comment: Yes, it was recently fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is showing correctly now, thanks SO team for fixing this!

Answer (score 0):

As per [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), Safari on iOS 8 is not supported. [The two most recent versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#Current_versions) are iOS 9 and iOS 10.

You should be able to upgrade your iPad Mini to iOS 9, but you'll probably take a noticeable performance hit.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. That is a shame though. Performance is also the exact reason I haven't upgraded to iOS 9 (Not enough upsides to outweigh the downsides).

Comment: I can confirm that the new top-bar works correctly on iOS 10. Can anyone confirm it is fine on iOS 9?