# Top bar messed up on iPad running iOS 9.3.5

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, top-bar

This is how the front page looks for me on the first iPad running iOS 9.3.5 (horizontal orientation):

[image]

The problem is, it's impossible to see the rest of the top bar, so I can't get access to messages, reputation changes and also Meta. *At all*. I literally had to click on the link to the "Should we burninate the [arrow] tag?" featured Meta question to get here. I always attempt to zoom out a bit, but that just triggers Safari's "open pages" view (<strike>how</strike> what is it called, BTW?).

No matter how far to the right I scroll (again, this design makes me want to zoom out just a little bit), the rightmost part of the top bar (circled in red) doesn't get scrolled with the rest of the page. As far as I remember, this wasn't always the case after the rollout of the new design, and I noticed this just some three weeks ago.

The same thing happens here on Meta. The top bars on other sites are fine <sup>(not really, see below)</sup>. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343367/4354477), iOS 9 should be supported, so that's a bug, to my mind.

---

Turns out, not all SE sites are fine: Math.se has the exact same problem, but, for example, Academia.se doesn't. So, this is a problem with the new top bar in general, not on SO only.

Comment: You are at 100% zoom to start with, right?

Comment: @DavyM, yes, and every time I open the site, it's shown as though it's been zoomed in.

Comment: Also, how am I supposed to see my messages, achievements and all the stuff from the very right of the top bar in vertical orientation, when the only thing shown on the top bar is the SO logo?? It's probably super responsive, but it's also very inconvenient and appears "zoomed in" as well.

Comment: It's 2018. Use iOS 11.

Comment: @Joshua, I can't: iOS 9.3.5 is the last version the first iPad supports. However, I should probably be using an iPad Pro in 2018 anyway :D

Comment: @ForceBru Holy crap you have the first iPad! lol

Comment: My gosh, this seems to have been fixed! Looks awesome! And the usability is back!